# Issues when spawn'ing ssh on expect ( {$var} vs. "$var" )

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl, expect

I have a expect script that so far it is working fine ... it spawn a ssh session over an existing ssh tunnel like this:

```
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o {ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:8888 %h %p} "$user_ip"
```

`$user_ip`has the username and destination IP, as expected by ssh, like `username@IP`

The problem is that sometimes, port 8888 is being used by another ssh tunnel, and every time this happens I have to tweak the code and change the tunnel port.

So, I am trying to send the port in a variable, to avoid touch the code all the time.
I am getting the tunnel port from command line, as:

```
set proxy_port [lindex $argv 2]
```

and then

```
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o {ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:"$proxy_port" %h %p} "$conn"
```

I see that `proxy_port`variable is properly set, but when the script try to spawn the ssh, I get:

```
 spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o {ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:8888 %h %p}  USERID@10.0.0.1
command-line line 0: garbage at end of line; "-o".
send: spawn id exp5 not open
    while executing
"send "$pwd\r""
    (file "./amm-qev.new.exp" line 36)
```

In the error above, I see that the port was properly replaced, but it is complaining about ssh syntax.

What is wrong there that my weak eyes are not catching ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww I agree that _"Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions"_ , however, totally disagree that _"it is not about programming or development"_. The question is about an issue while programming with **expect** script language ... like many posted on  **Stack Overflow**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl's `{...}` syntax is like single-quoted string (`'...'`) in shell where the `$var` would not be expanded. You should use double quotes.

```
spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
          -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
          -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x localhost:$proxy_port %h %p" \
          "$conn"
```